# Issues Launching Image with Data Volume using CoreOS and Fleet

Tags: docker, coreos

I have been trying to use FleetCtl to launch docker images one is a Data Volume Image and one is a Nginx Image launched with the --volumes-from option. The Nginx Image will not continue to run on the CoreOs server, but if I go to the server and type the command docker start the image starts and runs. Is there an image with launching Docker images that use a data volume with Fleet?

Docker File for Volume:

```
FROM busybox
MAINTAINER Zombie Possum

VOLUME  ["/usr/share/nginx/html", "/usr/share/nginx/conf"]

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY dist_nginx.conf /usr/share/nginx/conf/dist_nginx.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/true"]
```

Fleet File For Volume nginxData.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Data Container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
KillMode=none
User=core
WorkingDirectory=/home/core
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill DATA_NGINX
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm DATA_NGINX
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker pull private_repo/data_nginx:latest
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name DATA_NGINX private_repo/data_nginx:latest
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop DATA_NGINX
```

Fleet File for nginx.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx Container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
KillMode=none
User=core
WorkingDirectory=/home/core
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill NGINX
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm NGINX
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker pull private_repo/nginx:latest
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run  -rm -p 80:80 --name NGINX --volumes-from DATA_NGINX private_repo/nginx:latest
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop NGINX

[X-Fleet]
MachineOf=nginxData.service
```

Fleet Commands:

```
fleetctl submit nginxData.service
fleetctl submit nginx.service
fleetctl start nginxData.service
fleetctl start nginx.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dockerfile you provided runs with an error on my Docker host (without using fleet); maybe when fleet does detect that error it removes the container for you, while on a Docker host the container still exists in stopped state despite the error.

Here's the error:

```
$ docker build --force-rm -t so-26469566 .
$ docker run --name DATA_NGINX so-26469566
exec: "/usr/bin/true": stat /usr/bin/true: no such file or directory2014/10/20 16:59:54 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 767562758b9f30097a5ed16b98fe818d9c9574bb82b1cfd502bc3403e97d5b0
e: exec: "/usr/bin/true": stat /usr/bin/true: no such file or directory
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Try the following `CMD` statement in your Dockerfile and see if it does changes the behavior of fleet.

```
CMD ["/bin/true"]
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I tried it the way I listed it and with no CMD line at all and those did not work. The second container now seems to be picking up the volume now when I run against a local CoreOS cluster with fleet.

Answer (score 0):

If your nginx.service start and run runing the docker run command directly in CoreOS server, mayby your problem is not in docker image but nginx.service.

Notice you configure your service with:

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill NGINX
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm NGINX
```

trying to kill and remove NGINX container but you run the container with `--rm` which remove it automatically when it fail or exit.

Maybe your service not start because its `ExecStartPre` is failing

Try include

```
Requires=nginxData.service
After=nginxData.service
```

too.

Comment: This was an issue I had earlier, that is why I added the =- in the file, this will have the service file continue even when there is an issue with the line executing.